# Why does Imake interpret certain words in a Imakefile to numerical values?

Tags: linux, unix, makefile

I've found it very difficult to find any existing documentation on this.  What I'm trying to find out is why Imake would interpret a word such as `unix`, `linux` or `i386` to a number 1 in the produced Make-file?  I'm sure it is a function of indicating whether or not your on that system or not.  I've not been able to find that this is a #define set somewhere, so is this something that's built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imake produces Makefiles by running cpp, the C preprocessor, which usually has a variety of builtin definitions.  You can get a list by running

```
gcc -E -dM emptyfile.c
```